# Get the ID of the last node or relationship added

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I add a node:

```
CREATE (b:MyLabel{ Name : "Bob the Node", Disposition : "Happy" })
```

Later on I want to add another label to that node:

```
MATCH(n) WHERE ID(n) = 3   SET n:Circle
```

How would I get the **3**, or whatever it was when I added the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `ID` of a created node at the end using `RETURN`:

```
CREATE (b:MyLabel{ Name : "Bob the Node", Disposition : "Happy" }) RETURN ID(b)
```

Comment: Fantastic and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you should get a node.

To get the native ID of a node, you have to already have the node (or at least a relationship connected to that node).

You should design your data model in such a way that you can easily get the node through either its properties or its relationships. For example, if `MyLabel` nodes have unique `Name` values, then you could just do this:

```
MATCH (n:MyLabel {Name: "Bob the Node"})
SET n:Circle
```

*By the way, a native ID can be reused for a new node/relationship after the original node/relationship is deleted. So, unless you know what you are doing, you should not store a native ID somewhere and use it later.*